# ASP.NET Core & Node.js similarities

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, node.js, multithreading

I have been using Node.js for a while now. I know how it works internally (eventloop and other stuff) to a good extent but **ASP.NET Core** looks so similar to Node.js.

```
ASP.NET Core - Uses Kestrel (basically a fork of libuv)
Node.js - Uses libuv

ASP.NET Core - Tasks (though present in previous ASP.NET versions too)
Node.js - Promises

ASP.NET Core - Async/Await (though present in previous ASP.NET versions too)
Node.js - Async/Await
```

So, are the following conclusions correct:

Node.js has only a single thread for executing javascript code (sync) and many worker threads for background async operations.

ASP.NET Core uses multiple threads for executing .NET code (sync) and many worker threads for background async operations.

Node.js enforces I/O to be async so you don't block the event loop but in ASP.NET user can do sync I/O too hence blocking the thread, but since it uses multiple threads the whole app doesn't get blocked.

Answer (score 0):

I've no in depth information about Node JS, but based on your first part of comparison about kestrel and libuv, I should say that ASP.NET core is server independent. (I'm not talking about front web servers such as IIS, Apache, ...). There is a interface in ASP.NET Core named IServer, any implementation of that can be a asp.net core app server, Kesterl is one of your choices, You can use any Owin Compatible server or any other servers such as nowin & web listener.
ASP.NET core is pipeline independent (I'm not talking about middlewares), for example you can use Owin pipeline, asp.net core default pipeline and you can develop your own pipeline too.